# Not able to create ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error Initializing app: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:25:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443 (CLI v1.7.12)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b

Tried below commands:

npm cache clean
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/“

npm config set proxy http://<>:80

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy you need to get around, you can pass that proxy with the default http_proxy node environment variable or an environment variable proxy.

A few ways to set up and use the environment variable:

export http_proxy=internal.proxy.com
 Or
export PROXY=internal.proxy.com

ionic start my_app

It is working for me :)